# Kafka on Multiple Front & Back End Servers Causing Issues Of No Data Returning After A While

Tags: .net, .net-core, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have multiple Frontend UI and Backend .NET Core API instances running in Docker. Let's say 5 UI and 5 API pods/servers/instances running. When a user subscribes to Kafka on Frontend #1, maybe the initial setup is completed on Backend #5. Backend #5 subscribes to Kafka and returns data to Frontend #1. This works for a bit and then Frontend #1 stops getting data.

I think that this is because Frontend #1 stops hitting Backend #5 and instead hits a different backend server, say Backend #3. Because Backend #3 didn't set up the subscription to Kafka, no data is being returned.

Is the scenario above likely? Could the scenario above happen and describe why data would stop flowing to Frontend #1 server? If so, what is the correct way to link a Frontend and Backend server together for the life of the Kafka connection?

I also may not know what I am talking about so please let me know if that is the case as well. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The setup is: Browser -> Vue.js Front End App -> .Net Core API -> Kafka

The question, simply put, is does it matter if the Vue.js front end app contacts any of the backend API servers or will that break things?

Comment: Kafka isn't really a frontend technology, so are you using websockets?

Comment: Not really sure if I understood correctly, but do we have `[browser] --> [frontend node] --> [backend node] --> [kafka]` ? Is consumer group user-specific ? Or you manually assign topic partition offsets ?

Comment: @vpa1977 The consumer group is unique per user so each user will get all messages.

Comment: Could be either consumer not properly closed and still stuck on the other server, or a bug in the implementation, like you said with a missing subscribe call. Cant really provide an answer without looking at some diagram with the call chain. As for technology to use to feed your data - probably signalr is the answer - the connection is persistent and whatever backend node you hit first, you will stay with it.